# I'm having problem with zoneminder

Tags: zoneminder

[image]

I have this sort of errors in log, i can add cameras, but none of them are showing preview, and don't work

Comment: I am **not** able to read anything there - please consider copying the text and posting it either in your question or send it to a pastebin and [edit] your question to provide the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Keep the default zone apache.conf without the ScriptAlias.
2. Stop both zoneminder and apache2.

   ```
   sudo service apache2 stop
   sudo service zoneminder stop
   ```
3. Remove any stale sockets from `/tmp/zm` (default location).

   ```
   sudo rm -vf /tmp/zm/*.*
   ```
4. Enable cgi in apache.

   ```
   sudo a2enmod cgi
   ```
5. Start zoneminder.

   ```
   sudo service zoneminder start
   ```
6. Start apache2.

   ```
   sudo service apache2 start
   ```